# MasterPage property is always empty in content page

Tags: asp.net, delphi-prism, oxygene

I have a `HiddenField` on my master page, and its value is set in `Page_Load` event of the master page. In one of my content pages, I need this value in `Page_Load` event. So I added `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master"%>` to my content page, and created a property in the master page to read the hidden field's value. But, the `Page_Load` events seem to be fired in reverse order, that is, first the content page, and then the master page, because my property is always an empty string. Here's the code for my property `read` method and `Page_Load` event.

```
Site = public partial class(System.Web.UI.MasterPage)
  protected 
    method Page_Load(sender : object; e : EventArgs);
  private
    method GetCurrentCenter: String;
  public
    property CurrentCenter: String read GetCurrentCenter;
  end;

method Site.Page_Load(sender : object; e : EventArgs);
begin
  hfCurrentCenter.Value := '1';
end;

method Site.GetCurrentCenter: String;
begin
  Result := hfCurrentCenter.Value;
end;
```

And here's the `Page_Load` event in my content page:

```
method ContentPage.Page_Load(sender : object; e : EventArgs);
var
  Center: DropDownList;
begin
  if Master.CurrentCenter <> '-1' then  // --< Master.CurrentCenter is always an empty string
  begin
    Center := DropDownList(cuWizard.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("Center"));
    Center.Enabled := False;
  end;
end;
```

Why is `CurrentCenter` always an empty string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to page lifecycle. if you look at the order of firing of init and load events then you might get your answer.

```
INIT_EVENTS:
INIT_usercontrols
INIT_MasterPage
INIT_Page

LOAD Events:
Load :Page
Load: MasterPage
Load: UserControl
```

Comment: You are quite right. As I mentioned, the events are fired in that order. So, what should I do? Should I abandon my approach and place my hidden field on all my content pages?

Comment: Its an approach but i have not tried yet. assign the value in init event of masterpage so that it will be available to load event of page

Comment: I deleted my hidden field, and instead used a `Session` parameter in place of it. Everything works fine... Weird.

Comment: if you like my explanation,please visit my posts at codespread.com